# "Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp" when connected to RDS mySQL DB on Google Data Studio Report.

Tags: mysql, datetime, datasource, rds, looker-studio

I've successfully connected the RDS Database as a Data Source on Google Data Studio. The tables and fields within the tables are showing fine with the correct data types as well.

But when trying to create a Report using this data source, the `Time Dimension` dimension gives error :

```
Failed to execute connection with error: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
```

I tried adding `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` to the database name field when connecting but Google Data Studio does not accept the connection.

Any idea how to get this to work when some timestamps are `0000-00-00 00:00:00`?

Comment: The bigger question is how these zero timestamps ended up there in the first place.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we have a field called `last_login` which might never get activated as the user hasn't logged in.

Comment: Can you also show the query which is failing?  Or does the error happen before you even get that far?

Comment: The error comes up when trying to create a `time series` graph where one of the dimensions is a `time dimension`

Comment: You may have to clean up the source table.  The thing is, your reporting tool may be trying to convert that zero timestamp to seconds since epoch and then failing.

Comment: ok, thanks. Anyway to make it convert to null when importing the data into the data source? I know that adding this to the table name `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` does convert it and have used it on other tools, but for Google Data Studio, this doesn't work.

Comment: I was thinking of updating your SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve it using SQL, but you'll lost some data. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date != 0;
```